# URL rewrite PHP $_GET variable

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

Hey, I am looking to make a .htaccess rewrite file to change:

```
newProject/index.php?start=2
```

to

```
newProject/page/2
```

How might I go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? 99% of the times you want to do it the other way around.

Comment: lots of reasons. SEO, cleaner URL, wont let people tamper with my $_GET variables... mostly SEO though

Comment: Nazmun So you are actually asking the question backwards.

Answer (score 4):

I think your question is backwards, especially if you are looking for cleaner URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^newProject/page/(\d+)$ /newProject/index.php?start=$1
```

I assume that your users will click on URLs like `/newProject/page/2`, and a PHP script at `newProject/index.php` will access `$_GET['start']` to read the page number.

Comment: Im confused. I want to change the complicated GET variable TO the cleaner one..isnt that how i worded it?

Comment: @Nazmun: no, you want to use `mod_rewrite` to map the pretty URLs (what the user sees) to normal GET params (what PHP sees). You have worded it backwards.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for that I guess it sounded right in my head. I cant get his working. If it makes more sense, here is my complete URL:

http://studio-miller.com/newProject/index.php?start=2

Comment: The thing is. I think I am saying it how I mean it. I want to change the GET url to the cleaner one that uses folders.

Comment: @Nazmun: to avoid confusion, think of it from PHP's perspective. PHP wants to see normal GET URLs, so you need to convert the pretty one to what it wants.

Comment: That's true from the perspective of what your users see (you now want to print out clean URLs in your HTML). But your Apache server needs to change the clean URLs back into "dirty" ones so your PHP can handle it. Anyway, does your .htaccess file contain exactly those two lines and is it in your base directory (not in `newProject/`)?

Comment: Yes, my htaccess is in my home directory, er base directory. I was hoping apache would serve the PHP page before it converted the URL. I was hoping to do something like how the pagination is done on this page: http://designspiration.net

Comment: @Nazmun We're all on the same page. Rewriting /page/# to index.php?start=# is how you do that, and how you get URLs like that site. Your browser will ask for /page/2, your rule will tell Apache to handle that request with index.php. That's what mod_rewrite does.

Comment: Ok. ha, so do I just need to switch the order of the example first posted? Sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache 2.2.12 or later, consider using the FallbackResource directive instead. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html#fallback-resource for discussion of alternate techniques.