# How to include page with $_GET function & htaccess linking?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently developing a website and am wondering how to include pages into the main index (to only change a certain areas content and not the whole page) using the $_Get function.

Files would be something like index.php (where content pages are included), news.php (default page display on index), members.php, about.php, guides.php, downloads.php, sponsors.php etc.

I believe (if i remember correctly) linking with the $_Get method usually looks something like this index.php?pid=about

I would also like to find out how I can change the link (via htaccess?) to link as follows: www.mywebsite.com/about/ instead of mywebsite.com/index.php?pid=about

It has been some time since I have done any PHP and do not remember how the above things are done exactly.

Preview of what I am working on can be found at [www.survivaloperations.net/dev/](http://www.survivaloperations.net/dev/)

Comment: Sorry, but these types of questions are not really welcome here. One could write a book to answer this question, it's very broad. Search the web for tutorials. Voted to close.

Comment: It's worth noting that `$_GET` is not a function but an array of parameters passed through the URL. I'm also voting to close as this can be answered with a [2-second google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Google+mod_rewrite+%24_GET+parameter+PHP). More to the point, the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177738/url-rewrite-php-get-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would put all of your files in a pages folder, just reugular .php files.

your index.php would look like this:

```
include('pages/'. $_GET['pid']. '.php');
```

And so your files would look like:

```
pages/home.php
pages/contact.php
```

and you would go to:

```
index.php?pid=home
index.php?pid=contact
```

respectively

You would also want to have control over which $_GET values are allowed. I reccomend using a php switch:

```
 switch($_GET['pid']) {
      case "home": include("home.php"); break;
      case "contact": include("contact.php"); break;
      case "thing": include("thing.php"); break;
      default: include("404.php"); break;
 }
```

The switch requires less code than a bunch of else if statements, and allows for a default "404"-type page to be displayed when an invalid pid is entered. It also secures users from accessing anything they shouldn't... like "../db.php" or something (not sure if parent directory access is possible, but still).

Comment: You should at least mention that the parameter should be escaped or checked against a whitelist.

Comment: The `switch()` solution is *much* safer as you have a visible list of allowed names all in one place that can't be gamed.

Comment: So would the switch and the include be in the same place in the index.php (where i want the page content to be changing?) and thus the linking would be www.survivaloperations.net/about/ instead of survivaloperations.net/index.php?pid=about (due to the switch)?

Answer (score -1):

before use $_GET you must clear tags for safety.

```
$pid = strip_tags($_GET['pid']);
include("$path/" . $pid . ".php");
```

but... i prefer other code for safety.

```
$pid = strip_tags($_GET['pid']);
switch($pid) {
   'sub01' : include("$path/01.php"); break;
   'sub02' : include("$path/02.php"); break;
   default : include("$path/main.php");
}
```

Comment: why would $_GET['pid'] contain HTML tags?

Comment: Corbin// how can you make $_GET safe for XSS/CSRF?

Comment: XSS is a client-side issue, not server-side (cross-site-**scripting**). CSRF relates to stealing authentication tokens - again, a different problem. That said, yes accepting untested/unverified input is generally bad but I don't think this is the ideal solution by a long shot. It's clunky to maintain and your filenames are awful...

Comment: @OpenCode Think about a file path and what you need to be careful of.  HTML tags do not matter at all in a file path.  What matters is directory traversal (`/` in other words).  If paranoid, someone could also verify that a file path does not have any invalid characters.  The OS will handle that for you essentially though since the low level file opening calls will fail.  Always be aware of context when considering escaping.  Text should be escaped as HTML when it's in HTML.  Text should be escaped as SQL when it's in SQL.  So on.

Comment: I do not know about XSS/CSRF, security report sent to me said that fix it.
[link](http://www.exploitsdownload.com/search/hack/37)