# A secure dynamic PHP includes?

Tags: php, include

How do I create a dynamic PHP includes, that is secure? for example I have an index.php file with header.php and footer.php included inside of it and then grab other pages inbetween using

```
index.php?page=about
```

If possible it would need to be dynamic so using arrays and case would be time consuming and require modifications.

I also want to be able to change the title of website as well depending on what page was included.

I currently have this in place:

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/config.php';
//Set values for page  
$page_title = 'home page';
$current_page = 'home';

require_once 'includes/header.php';
?>


CONTENT


<?php
require_once 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```

Thanks

Would this be a safe way to include my pages?

```
if( isset( $_GET[ 'page' ] ) )
 {
   if( strpos( $_GET[ 'page' ], "/" ) )
     {
      $dir = substr( str_replace( ’’, ”, $_GET[ 'page' ] ), 0, strpos( $_GET[ 'page' ], "/" ) ) . "/";

      $file = substr( strrchr( $_GET['page' ], "/" ), 1 );
      if( file_exists( $dir.$file.".php" ) )
        {
         include( $dir.$file.".php" );
      } else {
         include( "home.php" );
      }
   } else {
      if( file_exists( basename( $_GET[ 'page' ] ).".php" ) ) 
        {
         include( basename( $_GET[ 'page' ] ).".php");
      } else {
         include( "404.php" );
      }
   }
} else {
   include( "home.php" );
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354484/how-to-include-page-with-get-function-htaccess-linking/11354526#11354526

Comment: If you are referring to romo's answer, then this didn't answer my question. It sort of relates to the second part of my question. However I have no control over what the title will say using that method except for the file name.

Comment: yes you do, just set your $page_title variable inside the switch. I am referring to the answer that i posting in the link above

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, I don't want to use a case/switch or arrays where I have to manually enter what pages will be included, due to the fact there will be a lot of pages to include.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent errors and unauthorized file access (secure) to pages outside of your web directory or invalid pages you should do the following.

Validate $_GET['page'] by checking for periods.  While periods may be valid in file names, it looks like you would be constructing the filename from the value and a period could indicate a breakout attempt to gain access to a root directory.

From there I would construct the filepath for the include, and then use file_exists to make sure it exists before including it.

As for the changing title for the page include I would do something like this:

```
<?php
$page_title = 'Default Title';
$page_to_include = 'default';

if( strpos($_GET['page'], '.') !== false ){
  //throw/display error - could be a breakout attempt
}
if( !file_exists(sprintf('page_includes/%s.php', $_GET['page'])) ){
  //requested page does not exists, throw or display error
}else{
  $page_to_include = sprintf('page_includes/%s.php', $_GET['page']);
}

//do page validation here with file_exists
ob_start();
include $page_to_include;
$included_page = ob_get_clean(); //gets contents and cleans the buffer and closes it

require_once 'includes/header.php';
echo $included_page;
require_once 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```

This way the page is included first and stored in a buffer rather that output.  It allows you included page to modify $page_title, and then that modified $page_title is available to the header.php script for output within the  tags.

Comment: Thank you this has made me able to change the page title dynamically :). Would a secure way to include the files in to index.php be like this? (I've added the code to my original question post)

Comment: Yes, that could definitely work, though I would use basename in the directory check as well, as you aren't checking for a breakout attempt there (../../).  Also if I read that correctly it looks like you would be losing any nested directories (dir1/dir2/dir3/file becomes dir1/file).

Answer (score 0):

Just to change the title?  Add this to your header.php

```
<title>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['page']) {
    echo $_GET['page'];
} else {
    echo 'My Site';
}
?>
</title>
```

Comment: I explained poorly. What I meant was if I had the file about.php to be included in to index.php have a variable inside of it for example:

`$page_title = 'About this site';`

Comment: use [isset function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php),   `echo isset($page_title)? $page_title:'untitled';`

Comment: You're probably going to need to create a seperate `title.php` file then because you can't include your page before the header and expect it to work.  Then you only have to create your 'case/switch' statement once.  You could also use javascript.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. However at the moment the title of the page is not a high priority. What I really want to know is a secure way of doing a dynamic PHP includes without using case/switch or arrays. In other words without having to manually enter what pages are to be included. So I can end up with `index.php?page=about`

Comment: What's wrong with the `$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'home'; include($page.'.php');`?

Comment: Well the site will have quite a lot of pages and having to keep adding  to statements would take a lot of time. That's why I stated without using case/switch or arrays. I want to use something along the lines of 
`$page = $_GET['page'];`
`if( file_exists( $page.".php" ) ) {
`include($page.".php");`
`}`
`else {`
`include("home.php");`
`}`
But of course a secure version of that